# Справочник методов Qt

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте! Начал изучать Qt5. И хотелось бы найти PDF справочник всех функций, методов, классов,какие имеются в Qt5, так как на сайт неудобно заходить постоянно за каждой функцией или классом. Есть ли такой? Язык справочника не важен.
Спасибо.

Comment: Эм... вместе с Qt Creator обычно ставится встроенная справка. Открывается по F1.

Comment: Grin L.  Спасибо, я что-то не подумал

Comment: Вот тут http://doc.qt.io/ всё что можно захотеть. Мне как-то в браузере удобнее, например, чем в окошке справки.